# Replace azure ad token with custom jwt token

Tags: angular, azure, .net-5

We are having angular 11 app as frontend and .net 5(latest) api at backend. We are having 2 login options 1. With basic authentication using user details saved in our system with JWT token generation and 2. Azure Ad authentication.
In our app during Azure Ad flow, we want to authenticate the 1st API call with Azure Ad token which will generate our own custom JWT token and then we want to replace Azure ad token with custom JWT token. Can you please help us with this requirement.

Comment: you can use angular interceptor

Answer (score 1):

As @[Edison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6781625/edison) said You can use **MSAL Interceptor** to meet your requirement .

Here is the [GitHub sample/Tutorial](https://github.com/tamani-coding/angular-msal-interceptor-example) to use MSAL interceptor in angular application to Call APIs with User Access Token.